# Error when trying to add more shapes in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

As part of my assignment, I'm supposed to make a shape that moves when the keyboard is pressed, and also changes color as it moves. I'm trying to add duplicate shapes that move when selected by clicking on them. However, for some reason, I can't add more than one shape. Here's my code. WARNING: MySimplePanel is very long, but the comments explain what my code does.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public interface ActionShape {

    /**
     * Calls the draw method inherited from the shape
     * @param g
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g);

    public boolean contains(double x, double y);

    public double getWidth();
    public double getHeight();

    public void setFrame(double x, double y, double w, double h);
}
```

**Driver.java**

```
    public class Driver {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MySimplePanel panel = new MySimplePanel(800, 800, Color.gray);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static float random(float lower, float upper) {
        float rand = (float) Math.random();
        float range = upper - lower;
        rand = range * rand;
        System.out.println((lower + rand));
        return (lower + rand);
    }

}
```

**myShape.java**

```
    public class myShape extends Rectangle2D.Double implements ActionShape{

    static final int size = 50;
    Ellipse2D oval;
    Ellipse2D oval2;
    Ellipse2D oval3;
    public int red=127;
    public int green=127;
    public int blue = 0;

    public myShape(int x, int y) {
        //sets position of square to center
        super(x-size/2, y-size/2, size, size);
        oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(x-size/2, y - size, size, size);
        oval2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x-size/2, y + size/25, size, size);
        oval3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x - size, y-size/2, size, size);
    }

    /**
     * Move all the shapes comprising this one
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.draw(this); //draw outline
        g.draw(oval);
        g.draw(oval2);
        g.draw(oval3);
        g.setColor(new Color(red,green,blue));//set color of all shapes
        g.fill(this); //draw inside
        g.fill(oval);
        g.fill(oval2);
        g.fill(oval3);
    }

    public void setFrame(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        super.setFrame(x, y, w, h);
        oval.setFrame(x, y-size/2, w, h);
        oval2.setFrame(x, y+size/2, w, h);
        oval3.setFrame(x-size/2, y, w, h);
    }

    public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
        if(super.contains(x, y) || oval.contains(x, y)|| oval2.contains(x, y)|| oval3.contains(x, y)) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MySimplepanel**

```
    public class MySimplePanel extends JPanel implements MouseInputListener, KeyListener{
    public static final int MOVE_PER_ARROW_KEY = 5; //variable that determines how many spaces the shape will move.
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean isPressed = false;
    private boolean rightPressed = false;
    private boolean otherPressed = false;
    public myShape shape;
    public int maxRed = 255;
    public int maxGreen = 255;
    public int maxBlue = 255;
    public myShape selShape=null;
    public int nextShape=0;
    //An array of different shapes that all share an interface. This  will be used when the right mouse button is pressed
    public myShape[] shapes;
    /**
     * Construct a panel with specified width, height, and background color
     * @param width
     * @param height
     * @param bgColor
     */
    public MySimplePanel(int width, int height, Color bgColor) {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.setBackground(bgColor);
        //Start to listen to mouse and keyboard input on this panel
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        this.addKeyListener(this); //detect keyboard input
        this.setFocusable(true); //allows you to select this window (required to be able to type in it, just like Processing)
        this.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); //disables shift and tab
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        //sets up the starting coordinates for each shape the shape is going to be on the panel.
        //I still need to align the center of the panel with the shape's center.
        shape = new myShape(400,400);   
        shapes = new myShape[100];  
        //array of shapes
        shapes[nextShape] = new myShape(200,200);
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called whenever you call repaint();
     */
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphicHelper) {
        super.paintComponent(graphicHelper); //basically background() in Processing, erases everything
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphicHelper; //used for drawing in 2D mode

        //width and height of the panel
        width= getWidth();
        height = getHeight();

        //draws the shape.
        shape.draw(g);


        for(int i=0;i<nextShape;i++) {
            shapes[i].draw(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.draw(shapes[i]);
        }

        //for the very first shape that is drawn
        if(isPressed==true) {
            shape.draw(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.draw(shape);
            System.out.println("Shape pressed");
        }

        //for the very other shape that is drawn by right-clicking
        if(otherPressed==true) {    
            for(int i=0;i<nextShape;i++) {
                selShape.draw(g);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.draw(selShape);
                System.out.println("Other Shape pressed");
            }
        }
        }



    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            if(shape.contains(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY())) {
                selShape=shape;
                isPressed=true;
                repaint();
        }   
        }   

        if(arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            for(int i=0; i<nextShape; i++) {
                if(shapes[i]!=null) {
                    if(shapes[i].contains(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY())) {
                        selShape=shapes[i];
                        otherPressed=true;  
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            rightPressed=true;
                if(rightPressed==true) {
                    selShape=shapes[nextShape];
                    nextShape++;
                    repaint();
                    }
                }       
        }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {


        /**
         * Scales the values of red and green based on the width and height respectively.
         *  red = 0 when the shape is all the way on the left, red = 255 when the shape is all the way on the right
         * green = 0 when the shape is all the way up, green = 255 when the shape is all the way down
         */
        selShape.red=(int) ((maxRed)*selShape.x/width);
        selShape.green=(int) ((maxGreen)*selShape.y/height);

        /**
         * These two if statements are meant to keep the shape from moving off screen.
         */
        if(selShape.x>width||selShape.x<(width=0)) {
            selShape.x=width;
        }
        if(selShape.y>height||selShape.y<(height=0)) {
            selShape.y=height;
        }


        /**
         * Moves the shape in different directions depending on the key pressed. It also changes the values of red and green 
         */
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            selShape.setFrame(selShape.x, selShape.y + MOVE_PER_ARROW_KEY,
                    selShape.width, selShape.height);   
            selShape.green--;   

            repaint();
        }else if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            selShape.setFrame(selShape.x, selShape.y - MOVE_PER_ARROW_KEY,
                    selShape.width, selShape.height);
            selShape.green++;


            repaint();
        }else if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            selShape.setFrame(selShape.x - MOVE_PER_ARROW_KEY, selShape.y,
                    selShape.width, selShape.height);
            selShape.red--;


            repaint();
        }else if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            selShape.setFrame(selShape.x + MOVE_PER_ARROW_KEY, selShape.y,
                    selShape.width, selShape.height);
            selShape.red++;

            repaint();
        }
        /**
         * If the shape reaches a certain spot, it will keep changing color randomly until it leaves that area.
         * 
         * Still trying to get the shape's center to hit that spot.
         *
         */
        if(selShape.getCenterX()>=50 && selShape.getCenterX()<=150 && selShape.getCenterY()>=50 && selShape.getCenterY()<=150) {
            selShape.red=(int)(Math.random()*maxRed)+1;
            selShape.green=(int)(Math.random()*maxGreen)+1;
            selShape.blue=(int)(Math.random()*maxBlue)+1;
            System.out.println("x: "+selShape.x);
            System.out.println("y: "+selShape.y);


        }   
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }
}
```

myShape.java

```
public class myShape extends Rectangle2D.Double implements ActionShape {

static final int size = 50;
Ellipse2D oval;
Ellipse2D oval2;
Ellipse2D oval3;
public int red = 127;
public int green = 127;
public int blue = 0;

public myShape(int x, int y) {
    // sets position of square to center
    super(x - size / 2, y - size / 2, size, size);
    oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(x - size / 2, y - size, size, size);
    oval2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x - size / 2, y + size / 25, size, size);
    oval3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x - size, y - size / 2, size, size);
}

/**
 * Move all the shapes comprising this one
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.draw(this); // draw outline
    g.draw(oval);
    g.draw(oval2);
    g.draw(oval3);
    g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));// set color of all shapes
    g.fill(this); // draw inside
    g.fill(oval);
    g.fill(oval2);
    g.fill(oval3);
}

public void setFrame(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
    super.setFrame(x, y, w, h);
    oval.setFrame(x, y - size / 2, w, h);
    oval2.setFrame(x, y + size / 2, w, h);
    oval3.setFrame(x - size / 2, y, w, h);
}

public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
    if (super.contains(x, y) || oval.contains(x, y) || oval2.contains(x, y) || oval3.contains(x, y)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Please review all code and give feedback." what is the error you're getting?

Comment: *"Please review all code and give feedback."* That's what [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is for. If you want attention here, please ask a question. *"MySimplePanel is very long"* But if you do that, condense the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: `As part of my assignment` - class names should start with an upper case character. I would fail you if you can't follow that basic convention and be consistent with all your classes. `I'm trying to add duplicate shapes` - don't use an Array with a random max size of 100. Instead use an ArrayList the doesn't have a limit. Don't design with random limitations. `I can't add more than one shape` - so what debugging have you done to isolate the problem? In the paintComponent() how many shapes do you have in the array? Does your KeyListener code work to duplicate the shape and add it to the array?